# How would you redirect calls to the top object in Cypress?

Tags: testing, cypress, end-to-end

In my application code, there are a lot of calls (like 100+) to the "top object" referring to window.top such as `top.$("title")` and so forth. Now, I've run into the problem using Cypress to perform end-to-end testing. When trying to log into the application, there are some calls to `top.$(...)` but the DevTools shows a `Uncaught TypeError: top.$ is not a function`. This resulted in my team and I discovering that the "top" our application is trying to reach is the Cypress environment itself.

The things I've **tried** before coming here are:

1) Trying to stub the window.top with the window object referencing our app. This resulted in us being told window.top is a read-only object.

2) Researching if Cypress has some kind of configuration that would smartly redirect calls to top in our code to be the top-most environment within our app. We figured we probably weren't the only ones coming across this issue.

If there were articles, I couldn't find any, so I came to ask if there was a way to do that, or if anyone would know of an alternate solution?

**Another** solution we considered: Looking into naming window objects so we can reference them by name instead of "window" or "top". If there isn't a way to do what I'm trying to do through Cypress, I think we're willing to do this as a last resort, but hopefully, we don't have to change that, since we're not sure how much of the app it will break upfront.

@Mikkel Not really sure what code I can provide to be useful, but here's the code that causes Cypress to throw the uncaught exception

```
if (sample_condition) {
  top.$('title').text(...).find('content') // Our iframe
} else {
  top.$('title').text(page_title)
}
```

And there are more instances in our code where we access the top object, but they are generally similar. We found out the root cause of the issue is that within Cypress calls to "top" actually interface with Cypress instead of their intended environment which is our app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could post some code as well it would help to understand your problem. Have you considered using the cypress `global` object?

Comment: @Mikkel I hope that code snippet and explanation helps, thanks! Also, I have not considered cypress `global`. Did not know that was a thing, thanks, I'm looking at it right now, but what are you suggesting about it that might be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a direct answer to your question, it's just expanding on your request for more information about the technique that I used to pass info from one script to another. I tried to do it within the same script without success - basically because the async nature of `.then()` stopped it from working.

This snippet is where I read a couple of id's from sessionStorage, and save them to a json file.

```
  //
  // At this point the cart is set up, and in sessionStorage
  // So we save the details to a fixtures file, which is read
  // by another test script (e2e-purchase.js)
  //
  cy.window().then(window => {
    const contents = {
      memberId: window.sessionStorage.getItem('memberId'),
      cartId: window.sessionStorage.getItem('mycart')
    }
    cy.writeFile(`tests/cypress/fixtures/cart.json`, contents)
  })
```

In another script, it loads the file as a fixture (`fixtures/cart.json`) to pull in a couple of id's

```
cy.fixture(`cart`).then(cart  => {
    cy.visit(`/${cart.memberId}/${cart.cartId}`)
})
```